# The different results by using mediacodec api between on 4.2 Jelly Bean emulator and nexus 4 device

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-debug

I'm working with the new API MediaCodec. I want to get the decoded video frame and render them on the surface at some scheduling time. Now I can run my code on emulator correctly and get the video frame format as following:

```
{height=192, what=1869968451, color-format=19, slice-height=192, crop-left=0, width=320, crop-bottom=179, crop-top=0, mime=video/raw, stride=320, crop-right=319}
```

But when I run my code on nexus 4, the video frame format is changed to

```
{height=180, what=1869968451, color-format=2141391875, slice-height=192, crop-left=0, width=320, crop-bottom=179, crop-top=0, mime=video/raw, stride=384, crop-right=319}
```

I can't find out what the color format 2141391875 is and why the height is not 192. A interesting problem is that when I modify the configure function from `codec.configure(format, surface /* surface */, null /* crypto */, 0 /* flags */)` to `codec.configure(format, null/* surface */, null /* crypto */, 0 /* flags */)`, the output buffer length will be changed from 0 to 114688. But actually, the correct buffer length should be 92160 if the frame format is YUV420p (320*192*1.5). I found that the output buffer was changed before output format changed when I run on emulator. But that was not changed when I run on nexus 4. The log is shown as follows,
On emulator:

```
03-26 14:42:38.466: I/VideoPlayTAG(1212): count=0
03-26 14:42:38.476: I/VideoPlayTAG(1212): sampleSize:700
03-26 14:42:38.496: D/VideoPlayTAG(1212): next:true
03-26 14:42:38.496: I/VideoPlayTAG(1212): output index:-3
03-26 14:42:38.566: D/VideoPlayTAG(1212): output buffers have changed.
03-26 14:42:38.566: I/VideoPlayTAG(1212): count=1
03-26 14:42:38.566: I/VideoPlayTAG(1212): sampleSize:140
03-26 14:42:38.596: D/VideoPlayTAG(1212): next:true
03-26 14:42:38.596: I/VideoPlayTAG(1212): output index:-2
03-26 14:42:38.686: D/VideoPlayTAG(1212): color=19 width=320 height=192
03-26 14:42:38.686: I/JNI(1212): begin setRender 1734
03-26 14:42:38.686: I/JNI(1212): setRender
03-26 14:42:38.716: D/VideoPlayTAG(1212): output format has changed to {height=192, what=1869968451, color-format=19, slice-height=192, crop-left=0, width=320, crop-bottom=179, crop-top=0, mime=video/raw, stride=320, crop-right=319}
03-26 14:42:38.716: I/VideoPlayTAG(1212): count=2
```

On nexus 4:

```
03-26 10:17:59.674: I/VideoPlayTAG(29899): count=0
03-26 10:17:59.684: I/VideoPlayTAG(29899): sampleSize:700
03-26 10:17:59.684: D/VideoPlayTAG(29899): next:true
03-26 10:17:59.694: I/VideoPlayTAG(29899): output index:-1
03-26 10:17:59.694: I/VideoPlayTAG(29899): count=1
03-26 10:17:59.704: I/VideoPlayTAG(29899): sampleSize:140
03-26 10:17:59.704: D/VideoPlayTAG(29899): next:true
03-26 10:17:59.704: I/VideoPlayTAG(29899): output index:-1
03-26 10:17:59.714: I/VideoPlayTAG(29899): count=2
03-26 10:17:59.714: I/VideoPlayTAG(29899): sampleSize:131
03-26 10:17:59.714: D/VideoPlayTAG(29899): next:true
03-26 10:17:59.724: I/VideoPlayTAG(29899): output index:-1
03-26 10:17:59.724: I/VideoPlayTAG(29899): count=3
03-26 10:17:59.724: I/VideoPlayTAG(29899): sampleSize:59
03-26 10:17:59.724: D/VideoPlayTAG(29899): next:true
03-26 10:17:59.724: I/VideoPlayTAG(29899): output index:-2
03-26 10:17:59.744: D/VideoPlayTAG(29899): color=2141391875 width=320 height=180
03-26 10:17:59.744: I/JNI(29899): begin setRender 1734
03-26 10:17:59.744: I/JNI(29899): setRender
03-26 10:17:59.744: D/VideoPlayTAG(29899): output format has changed to {height=180, what=1869968451, color-format=2141391875, slice-height=192, crop-left=0, width=320, crop-bottom=179, crop-top=0, mime=video/raw, stride=384, crop-right=319}
03-26 10:17:59.744: I/VideoPlayTAG(29899): count=4
```

Can anyone help me?
I found the problem may be caused by the difference of software render and hardware render.

Answer (score 1):

1. 2141391875 (0x7fa30c03) is a NV12 adreno tiled (aka HAL_PIXEL_FORMAT_NV12_ADRENO_TILED, aka HAL_PIXEL_FORMAT_YCbCr_420_SP_TILED). This color format has pixel data ordered optimal way for hardware processing.
2. Picture height in emulator is not 192 as well. Please pay attention: it says "crop-bottom=179". This means that heights are actually the same (180).
3. 114688 bytes is a proper size for the buffer. It is calculated this way = slice-height(192) * stride(384) * 1.5 and aligned with 8K.
4. INFO_OUTPUT_FORMAT_CHANGED and INFO_OUTPUT_BUFFERS_CHANGED have different sense, those order does not matter.

Still see no problem, everything looks ok.